# Parallel.ForEach MaxDegreeOfParallelism Strange Behavior with Increasing "Chunking"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm not sure if the title makes sense, it was the best I could come up with, so here's my scenario.

I have an ASP.NET Core app that I'm using more as a shell and for DI configuration. In `Startup` it adds a bunch of `IHostedService`s as singletons, along with their dependencies, also as singletons, with minor exceptions for `SqlConnection` and `DbContext` which we'll get to later. The hosted services are groups of similar services that:

1. Listen for incoming reports from GPS devices and put into a listening buffer.
2. Parse items out of the listening buffer and put into a parsed buffer.

Eventually there's a single service that reads the parsed buffer and actually processes the parsed reports. It does this by passing the report it took out of the buffer to a handler and awaits for it to complete to move to the next. This has worked well for the past year, but it appears we're running into a scalability issue now because its processing one report at a time and the average time to process is 62ms on the server which includes the Dapper trip to the database to get the data needed and the EF Core trip to save changes.

If however the handler decides that a report's information requires triggering background jobs, then I suspect it takes 100ms or more to complete. Over time, the buffer fills up faster than the handler can process to the point of holding 10s if not 100s of thousands of reports until they can be processed. This is an issue because notifications are delayed and because it has the potential for data loss if the buffer is still full by the time the server restarts at midnight.

All that being said, I'm trying to figure out how to make the processing parallel. After lots of experimentation yesterday, I settled on using `Parallel.ForEach` over the buffer using `GetConsumingEnumerable()`. This works well, except for a weird behavior I don't know what to do about or even call. As the buffer is filled and the `ForEach` is iterating over it it will begin to "chunk" the processing into ever increasing multiples of two. The size of the chunking is affected by the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` setting. For example (N# = Next # of reports in buffer):

##### MDP = 1

- N3 = 1 at a time
- N6 = 2 at a time
- N12 = 4 at a time
- ...

##### MDP = 2

- N6 = 1 at a time
- N12 = 2 at a time
- N24 = 4 at a time
- ...

##### MDP = 4

- N12 = 1 at a time
- N24 = 2 at a time
- N48 = 4 at a time
- ...

##### MDP = 8 (my CPU core count)

- N24 = 1 at a time
- N48 = 2 at a time
- N96 = 4 at a time
- ...

This is arguably worse than the serial execution I have now because by the end of the day it will buffer and wait for, say, half a million reports before actually processing them.

Is there a way to fix this? I'm not very experienced with `Parallel.ForEach` so from my point of view this is strange behavior. Ultimately I'm looking for a way to parallel process the reports as soon as they are in the buffer, so if there's other ways to accomplish this I'm all ears. This is roughly what I have for the code. The handler that processes the reports does use `IServiceProvider`  to create a scope and get an instance of `SqlConnection` and `DbContext`. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```cs
public sealed class GpsReportService :
    IHostedService {
    private readonly GpsReportBuffer _buffer;
    private readonly Config _config;
    private readonly GpsReportHandler _handler;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public GpsReportService(
        GpsReportBuffer buffer,
        Config config,
        GpsReportHandler handler,
        ILogger<GpsReportService> logger) {
        _buffer = buffer;
        _config = config;
        _handler = handler;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        _logger.LogInformation("GPS Report Service => starting");

        Task.Run(Process, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);//   Is ConfigureAwait here correct usage?

        _logger.LogInformation("GPS Report Service => started");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        _logger.LogInformation("GPS Parsing Service => stopping");

        _buffer.CompleteAdding();

        _logger.LogInformation("GPS Parsing Service => stopped");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    //  ========================================================================
    //  Utilities
    //  ========================================================================

    private void Process() {
        var options = new ParallelOptions {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8,
            CancellationToken = CancellationToken.None
        };

        Parallel.ForEach(_buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable(), options, async report => {
            try {
                await _handler.ProcessAsync(report).ConfigureAwait(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (_config.IsDevelopment) {
                    throw;
                }

                _logger.LogError(e, "GPS Report Service");
            }
        });
    }

    private async Task ProcessAsync() {
        while (!_buffer.IsCompleted) {
            try {
                var took = _buffer.TryTake(out var report, 10);

                if (!took) {
                    continue;
                }

                await _handler.ProcessAsync(report!).ConfigureAwait(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (_config.IsDevelopment) {
                    throw;
                }

                _logger.LogError(e, "GPS Report Service");
            }
        }
    }
}

public sealed class GpsReportBuffer :
    BlockingCollection<GpsReport> {
}
```

Comment: You appear to be mixing up tasks and threads, which is never a good idea.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is meant for data parallelism,not async operations. It's meant to process large chunks of in-memory data by partitioning it and using roughly one worker task per CPU core, to reduce synchronization between cores. It will even use the current thread which leads to the mistaken assumption it's blocking. When all cores are busy, why *not* use the thread? It won't be able to run anyway. It's *not* meant to handle streams of messages, async operations or start other threads. Using Task.Run with it is counterproductive - Parallel.ForEach will use all cores anyway

Comment: You can simplify the problem immensely if you use the correct classes - Dataflow blocks or Channels instead of BlockingCollection and Parallel.Foreach

Comment: How are you processing the GPS data? [Reactive Extensions](http://reactivex.io/) allows processing, aggregation and analytics over streams of events. You could use it to eg calculate the distance traveled per "thing" in a specific time window using LINQ-like operations, eg `events.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).Select(list=>list.Average(gps=>gps.Speed));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `Parallel` methods with `async` delegates - at least, not yet.

Since you already have a "pipeline" style of architecture, I recommend looking into TPL Dataflow. A single `ActionBlock` may be all that you need, and once you have that working, other blocks in TPL Dataflow may replace other parts of your pipeline.

If you prefer to stick with your existing buffer, then you should use asynchronous concurrency instead of `Parallel`:

```
private void Process() {
  var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(8);
  var tasks = _buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable()
      .Select(async report =>
      {
        await throttler.WaitAsync();
        try {
          await _handler.ProcessAsync(report).ConfigureAwait(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          if (_config.IsDevelopment) {
            throw;
          }

          _logger.LogError(e, "GPS Report Service");
        }
        finally {
          throttler.Release();
        }
      })
      .ToList();
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: I did try non-async delegate with just _handler.ProcessAsync(report), but it was the same result. I’ve never used semaphors, so I have a question… You do a ToList on the buffer, but what happens if the buffer is emptied out? Does execution stop, or waits for a new item? Guess I’ll just have to try it and see, with Parallel.ForEach it kept going, so I assume this will too.

Comment: `ProcessAsync` is still an asynchronous delegate type, since it returns a task. `GetConsumingEnumerable` will complete when the buffer is empty and has been marked complete.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the `var tasks = _buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable().Select(/*...*/).ToList();` statement will block until the `_buffer` completes. So it probably makes more sense to also block while waiting for the completion of the last few incomplete tasks: `Task.WaitAll(tasks);` instead of `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

Comment: The problem becomes a lot simpler if `Channel` is used instead of `BlockingCollection`

Comment: I've implemented the `SemaphorSlim` example and it seems to be working well now, or at least its keeping up until I can look into replacing it all with either a Dataflow or Channels implementation. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You have an event stream processing/dataflow problem, not a parallelism problem. If you use the appropriate classes, like the [Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) blocks,  [Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/), or [Reactive Extensions](http://reactivex.io/) the problem is simplified a *lot*.

Even if you want to use a single buffer and a fat worker method though, the appropriate buffer class is the asynchronous [Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel?view=net-5.0), not BlockingCollection. The code could become as simple as:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    await foreach(GpsMessage msg in _reader.ReadAllAsync(stopppingToken))
    {
       await _handler.ProcessAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

The first option shows how to use a Dataflow to create a pipeline. The second, how to use `Channel` instead of `BlockingCollection` to process multiple queued items concurrently

**A pipeline with Dataflow**

Once you break the process into independent *methods*, it's easy to create a pipeline of processing steps using any library.

```
Task<IEnumerable<GpsMessage>> Poller(DateTime time,IList<Device> devices,CancellationToken token=default)
{
    foreach(var device in devices)
    {
        if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }
        var msg=await device.ReadMessage();
        yield return msg;
    }
}

GpsReport Parser(GpsMessage msg)
{
    //Do some parsing magic. 
    return report;
}

async Task<GpsReport> Enrich(GpsReport report,string connectionString,CancellationToken token=default)
{
    //Depend on connection pooling to eliminate the cost of connections
    //We may have to use a pool of opened connections otherwise
    using var con=new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    var extraData=await con.QueryAsync<Extra>(sql,new {deviceId=report.DeviceId},token);
    report.Extra=extraData;
    return report;
}

async Task BulkImport(SqlReport[] reports,CancellationToken token=default)
{
    using var bcp=new SqlBulkCopy(...);
    using var reader=ObjectReader.Create(reports);
    ...
    await bcp.WriteToServerAsync(reader,token);
}
```

In the BulkImport method I use [FasMember's ObjectReader](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member#ever-needed-an-idatareader) to create an IDataReader wrapper over the reports so I can use them with SqlBulkCopy. Another option would be to convert them to a DataTable, but that would create an extra copy of the data in memory.

Combining all these with Dataflow is relatively easy.

```
var execOptions=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
}

_poller      = new TransformManyBlock<DateTime,GpsBuffer>(time=>Poller(time,devices));
_parser      = new TransformBlock<GpsBuffer,GpsReport>(b=>Parser(b),execOptions);
var enricher = new TransformBlock<GpsReport,GpsReport>(rpt=>Enrich(rpt,connStr),execOptions);
_batch       = new BatchBlock<GpsReport>(50);
_bcpBlock    = new ActionBlock<GpsReport[]>(reports=>BulkImport(reports));
```

Each block has an input and output buffer (except ActionBlock). Each block takes care of processing the messages in its input buffer and processes it. By default, each block uses only one worker task, but that can be changed. The message order is maintained, so if we use eg 10 worker tasks for the `parser` block, the messages will still be emitted in the order they were received.

Next comes linking the blocks.

```
var linkOptions=new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion=true};

_poller.LinkTo(_parser,options);
_parser.LinkTo(_enricher,options);
_enricher.LinkTo(_batch,options);
_batch.LinkTo(_bcpBlock,options);
```

After that, a timer can be used to "ping" the head block, the poller, whenever we want:

```
private void Ping(object state)
{
    _poller.Post(DateTime.Now);
}

public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");

    _timer = new Timer(Ping, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

To stop the pipeline gracefully, we call `Complete()` on the head block and await the `Completion` task on the last block. Assuming the hosted service is similar to the [timed background service example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks):

```
public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
{

    ....
    _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
    _poller.Complete();
    await _bcpBlock.Completion;
    ...
}
```

**Using Channel as an Async queue**

A Channel is a far better alternative for asynchronous publisher/subscriber scenarios than BlockingCollection. Roughly, it's an asynchronous queue that goes to extremes to *prevent* the publisher from reading, or the subscriber from writing, by forcing callers to use the ChannelWriter and ChannelReader classes. In fact, it's quite common to only pass those classes around, never the Channel instance itself.

In your publishing code, you can create a `Channel<T>` and pass its Reader to the `GpsReportService` service. Let's assume the publisher is another service that implements an `IGpsPublisher` interface :

```
public interface IGpsPublisher
{
    ChannelReader<GspMessage> Reader{get;}
}
```

and the implementation

```
Channel<GpsMessage> _channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<GpsMessage>();

public ChannelReader<GspMessage> Reader=>_channel;

private async void Ping(object state)
{
    foreach(var device in devices)
    {
        if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }
        var msg=await device.ReadMessage();
        await _channel.Writer.WriteAsync(msg);
    }
}

public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{

    _timer = new Timer(Ping, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
{
    _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
    _channel.Writer.Complete();
}
```

This can be passed to GpsReportService as a dependency that will be resolved by the DI container:

```
public sealed class GpsReportService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ChannelReader<GpsMessage> _reader;


    public GpsReportService(
        IGpsPublisher publisher,
        ...) 
    {
        _reader = publisher.Reader;
        ...
    }
```

And used

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    await foreach(GpsMessage msg in _reader.ReadAllAsync(stopppingToken))
    {
       await _handler.ProcessAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

Once the publisher completes, the subscriber loop will also complete once all messages are processed.

To process in parallel, you can start multiple loops concurrently:

```
async Task Process(ChannelReader<GgpsMessage> reader,CancellationToken token)
{
    await foreach(GpsMessage msg in reader.ReadAllAsync(token))
    {
       await _handler.ProcessAsync(msg);
    }
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    var tasks=Enumerable.Range(0,10)
                 .Select(_=>ProcessReader(_reader,stoppingToken))
                 .ToArray();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

**Explaining the pipeline**

I have a similar situation: every 15 minutes I request air ticket sales reports from airlines (actually [GDSs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_distribution_system)), parse them to extract data and ticket numbers, download the ticket record for each ticket to get some extra data and save everything to the database. I have to do that for 20+ cities (ticket reports are per city) with each report having from 10 to over 100K tickets.

This almost begs for a pipeline. Using your example, you can create a pipeline with the following steps/blocks:

1. Listen for GPS messages and emit the *unparsed* message.
2. Parse the message and emit the *parsed* message
3. Load any extra data needed per message and emit a combined record
4. Handle the combined record and emit the result
5. (Optional) batch results
6. Save the results to the database

All three options (Dataflow, Channels, Rx) take care of buffering between the steps. Dataflow is a some-assembly-required library for pipelines processing independent events, Rx is ready-made to analyze streams of events where time is important (eg to calculate average speed in a sliding window), Channels is Lego bricks that can do anything but need to be put together.

**Why not Parallel.ForEach**

`Parallel.ForEach` is meant for data parallelism, not async operations. It's meant to process large chunks of in-memory data, independent of each other. [Amdah's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) explains that parallelization benefits are limited by the *synchronous* part of an operation, so all data parallelism libraries try to reduce that by partitioning, and using one core/machine/node to process each partition.

`Parallel.ForEach` also works by partitioning the data and using roughly one worker task per CPU core, to reduce synchronization between cores. It will even use the current thread which leads to the mistaken assumption it's blocking. When all cores are busy, why not use the thread? It won't be able to run anyway.

Comment: I will be looking into implementing a Dataflow and a Channels version to 1) learn more about them and 2) which one will be the ultimate winner. For now the `SemaphorSlim` implementation is keeping up and has bought me the time needed to look into both of those. I have to admit Channels intimidated me when I read about it when it got announced, but I guess its just because I don't understand how to use them. Thanks for the examples, I will be referencing them when I start working on the overhaul.

Comment: `I don't understand how to use them` that's something I've been complaining about for a long time. There are no good tutorials about them. [Steve Gordon's article](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels) can help as a starter, and  [Stephen Toub's goes into greater depth](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) goes into greater depth into why things work the way they do

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c the problem with SemaphoreSlim though is that order isn't preserved. There's no guarantee that the GPS messages will be processed in the order they're received. You won't be able to perform any processing in memory without buffering and sorting events, and you'll definitely end up with messages out of order in the database, requiring a sort by timestamp to retrieve in order

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c with GPS and event processing in general, order matters. With guaranteed order, you can calculate the distance between points simply by comparing with the well-known previous point. Essentially, you only need to cache one point. Without order, there's no way to know if you're missing a point. You'd need infinite caching for this, or at least, a *lot* of caching. Never mind more complex stuff like anomaly detection or tracking. Or just using sliding windows to calculate statistics

Answer (score 1):

The `Parallel.ForEach` employs chunk partitioning by default, which is intended for reducing the synchronization overhead in CPU-intensive applications, but can result to problematic behavior in some usage scenarios. The chunk partitioning can be disabled by passing as argument a [`Partitioner<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner-1) instead of an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(_buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable(),
    EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering), options, ...
```

You can also find a custom partitioner, tailored specifically for `BlockingCollection<T>`s, in this article: [ParallelExtensionsExtras Tour – #4 – BlockingCollectionExtensions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-4-blockingcollectionextensions/)

That said, the `Parallel.ForEach` is not async-friendly, meaning that it doesn't understand async delegates. The lambda passed is `async void`, which is [something to avoid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). So I would recommend using an [`ActionBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) instead.